# case statement in select when creating a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

> Missing keyword error in line 4

I am using oracle sql

```
SELECT invoice_num, invoice_item, sales_order_num, sales_order_item, NET_aMT, list_amt, COST_PERCENT,
case when product_type_code='PTO' 
THEN 0
ELSE INV_AMT COST_PERCENT over (PARTITION BY sales_order_num, sales_order_item,invoice_num)
END
ALLOC_NET
FROM(
select invoice_num, invoice_item, sales_order_num, sales_order_item, NET_aMT, list_amt, 
case when p.product_type_code IN ('PTO','ATO') 
then sum(NET_AMT) over (PARTITION BY sales_order_num, sales_order_item, invoice_num) 
else 0
end
as INV_AMT,
cost_amt,
case when p.product_type_code = 'ATO' 
then SUM(cost_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_order_num, sales_order_item, invoice_num) 
else 0 
as pto_cost,
case when p.product_type_code = 'ATO' 
then (cost_amt/SUM(cost_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_order_num, sales_order_item, invoice_num))
else 0 
end as cost_percent,
p.product_type_code
from edw.w_sales_invoice_line_f f, edw.w_product_d p
where f.sales_order_num = '11574425' and f.product_wid = p.row_wid and sales_order_item IN ( '5','1','2','3')
AND invoice_item!=1
);
```

I get:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column:
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `CASE` seems to be invalid:

```
case when product_type_code='PTO' THEN 0 
     ELSE INV_AMT*COST_PERCENT over (PARTITION BY sales_order_num, sales_order_item,invoice_num) 
END ALLOC_NET
```

Looks like you thought that `COST_PERCENT` is analytic function, but - documentation disagrees (i.e. I never heard of it, Google doesn't return anything). Could you explain what it is?

Comment: cost_percent is just an alias that i am using

Comment: OK, so it isn't an analytic function so you can't use "over (partition by ..." part (not the way you're doing it now, that is).

Comment: @devapundir maybe you want something like: `sum(INV_AMT*COST_PERCENT) over(....)`